# Why can't I set size like this?? -_-

Tags: arrays, blockchain, solidity

SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract check{
`

```
 uint public size;
    
    function setSize(uint s) public {
        size = s;
    } 

    uint[size] arr;  // I can't do this....this shows error...plz help ;-;
    
    function SetArray() public {   // set `enter code here`
        for(uint i=0; i<size; i++){
            arr[i] = i+1;
        }
    }

    function getArray() public view returns(uint[size] memory){
        return arr;
    }
```

}

Check the image for the compilation error :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxD6j.png

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic size

```
uint[] arr;
```

Fixed size

```
uint arr[size];
```

The **size** must be an integer constant greater than zero

Comment: Aye ...thanks...but it don't work....m using setSize() function to set the constant size value....but it shows compilation error.

Comment: I think you should modify the line `uint[size] arr;` to `uint[] arr;`, because the size variable is not initialized in the first line.

Comment: ya...it worked that way...thanks